# Filtering a Snowflake SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql, json, nosql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to find a good maybe subquery strategy to select a value within a document by matching another value, with multiple documents. I *can* execute a query, but not in a scalable methodology for data that changes. Imagine I have the below dataset:

```
{
    "company": [{
            "company_data": [{
                "Org": "Company1",
                "Position": "Manager",
                "Department": "Engineering",
                "Name": "JohnDoe"
            }, {
                "Org": "Company1",
                "Position": "SrEngineer",
                "Department": "Engineering",
                "Name": "JaneDoe"
            }, {
                "Org": "Company1",
                "Position": "StaffEngineer",
                "Department": "Engineering",
                "Name": "JamesDoe"
            }]
        },
        {
            "company_data": [{
                "Org": "Company2",
                "Position": "Manager",
                "Department": "Engineering",
                "Name": "JohannaDoe"
            }, {
                "Org": "Company2",
                "Position": "SrEngineer",
                "Department": "Engineering",
                "Name": "FidoDoe"
            }, {
                "Org": "Company2",
                "Position": "StaffEngineer",
                "Department": "Engineering",
                "Name": "BaileyDoe"
            }, {
                "Org": "Company2",
                "Position": "Intern",
                "Department": "Fetching",
                "Name": "BaileyDoe"
            }]
        }, {
            "company_data": [{
                "Org": "Company3",
                "Position": "Custodian",
                "Department": "Operations",
                "Name": "AristotleDoe"
            }, {
                "Org": "Company3",
                "Position": "SrEngineer",
                "Department": "Engineering",
                "Name": "SocratesDoe"
            }, {
                "Org": "Company3",
                "Position": "Manager",
                "Department": "Engineering",
                "Name": "BaconDoe"
            }, {
                "Org": "Company3",
                "Position": "Intern",
                "Department": "Fetching",
                "Name": "NietzcheDoe"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I write a query that pulls the name of the manager from each document? This is to form a table like:

```
COMPANY     MANAGER     CONTENTS
Company1    JohnDoe     [{'Position':'Manager',...*json*...}]
Company2    JohannaDoe  [{'Position':'Manager',...*json*...}]
Company3    BaconDoe    [{'Position':'Custodian',...*json*...}]
```

In my real dataset I can usually depend on indexing in the select statement. In the typical case that would be selecting the first value:

```
SELECT 
     company:company_data:Org as company, 
     company:company_data[0]:Name as manager,
     company:company_data as contents
FROM
     poorly_imagined_table;
```

But in the 3rd case, the manager is not a part of the first entry [0]. How can I filter the SQL statement so that it looks something like this (which does not work)?

```
SELECT 
     company:company_data:Org as company, 
     company:company_data[WHERE company:company_data:Position = 'Manager']:Name as manager,
     company:company_data as contents
FROM
     poorly_imagined_table;
```

Note: a standard WHERE clause below SELECT does not work in this case since I need to specifically match a value when selecting rather than filtering lower with WHERE.

Let me know if anyone has a suggestion! Thanks!

Comment: That JSON is not valid. It may be possible to correct by making some assumptions about its structure, but it would be better if you could make sure it validates somewhere like `jsonlint.com` and update the question.

Comment: I attempted to fix the JSON structure in the way that seemed to make the most sense. If this is not correct, please update the question with JSON that validates.

Answer (score 1):

You need to flatten this twice, once to flatten the `company` array and once to flatten the `company_data` array inside each `company`:

```
create or replace table T1(V variant);

insert into T1 select parse_json($$ <Your JSON>  $$);
```

If you're just looking to get the information for the managers:

```
select   CD.VALUE:Org::string  as COMPANY
        ,CD.VALUE:Name::string as MANAGER
        ,CD.VALUE              as CONTENTS
from     T1
        ,table(flatten(v:company)) C
        ,table(flatten(VALUE:company_data)) CD
where    CD.VALUE:Position::string ilike 'Manager'
;
```

Output:

| COMPANY | MANAGER | CONTENTS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Company1 | JohnDoe | { `company_data` object here... } |
| Company2 | JohannaDoe | { `company_data` object here... } |
| Company3 | BaconDoe | { `company_data` object here... } |

If you're trying to get the information for all employees and relate them to their managers:

```
with EMPLOYEE_LIST as
(
select   CD.VALUE:Org::string  as COMPANY
        ,CD.VALUE:Name::string as EMPLOYEE_NAME
        ,CD.VALUE              as CONTENTS
from     T1
        ,table(flatten(v:company)) C
        ,table(flatten(VALUE:company_data)) CD
), MANAGER_LIST as
(
select COMPANY, EMPLOYEE_NAME from EMPLOYEE_LIST
where  CONTENTS:Position::string ilike 'Manager'
)
select   E.COMPANY
        ,E.EMPLOYEE_NAME
        ,M.EMPLOYEE_NAME as MANAGER
        ,CONTENTS
from    EMPLOYEE_LIST E
    left join MANAGER_LIST M on E.COMPANY = M.COMPANY
;
```

Output:

| COMPANY | EMPLOYEE_NAME | MANAGER | CONTENTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company1 | JohnDoe | JohnDoe | `company_data` object here... |
| Company1 | JaneDoe | JohnDoe | `company_data` object here... |
| Company1 | JamesDoe | JohnDoe | `company_data` object here... |
| Company2 | JohannaDoe | JohannaDoe | `company_data` object here... |
| Company2 | FidoDoe | JohannaDoe | `company_data` object here... |
| Company2 | BaileyDoe | JohannaDoe | `company_data` object here... |
| Company2 | BaileyDoe | JohannaDoe | `company_data` object here... |
| Company3 | AristotleDoe | BaconDoe | `company_data` object here... |
| Company3 | SocratesDoe | BaconDoe | `company_data` object here... |
| Company3 | BaconDoe | BaconDoe | `company_data` object here... |
| Company3 | NietzcheDoe | BaconDoe | `company_data` object here... |

Comment: Greg, thanks for these great and detailed response (and fixing my poorly constructed JSON). Let me take a look and see how I can apply it to my actual dataset and get back to you.

Comment: When you are tabling & flattening, v: is used to specify the column, and that table (C) is also supposed to feed into the next tabling & flattening, where you specify VALUE. Why is C not referenced to create CD? Alternatively, how come you cannot jump directly to flattening the targeted item ('company_data')? I've been trying to apply this to my dataset, but unable to even select/view the newly created tables. Thanks!

Comment: Got it working on my actual dataset with a few mods! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it makes sense to get out of SQL and into a JS/Python UDF when parsing documents.

This one would do it:

```sql
create or replace function find_manager(company_data variant)
returns string
language python
handler = 'x'
runtime_version = '3.8'
as $$
def x(company_data):
    for dep in company_data:
        if dep['Position'] == 'Manager':
            return dep['Name']
```

In action:

```sql
with data as (
select $$
{
    "company": [{
            "company_data": [{
                "Org": "Company1",
                "Position": "Manager",
                "Department": "Engineering",
                "Name": "JohnDoe"
            }, {
                "Org": "Company1",
                "Position": "SrEngineer",
                "Department": "Engineering",
                "Name": "JaneDoe"
            }, {
                "Org": "Company1",
                "Position": "StaffEngineer",
                "Department": "Engineering",
                "Name": "JamesDoe"
            }]
        },
        {
            "company_data": [{
                "Org": "Company2",
                "Position": "Manager",
                "Department": "Engineering",
                "Name": "JohannaDoe"
            }, {
                "Org": "Company2",
                "Position": "SrEngineer",
                "Department": "Engineering",
                "Name": "FidoDoe"
            }, {
                "Org": "Company2",
                "Position": "StaffEngineer",
                "Department": "Engineering",
                "Name": "BaileyDoe"
            }, {
                "Org": "Company2",
                "Position": "Intern",
                "Department": "Fetching",
                "Name": "BaileyDoe"
            }]
        }, {
            "company_data": [{
                "Org": "Company3",
                "Position": "Custodian",
                "Department": "Operations",
                "Name": "AristotleDoe"
            }, {
                "Org": "Company3",
                "Position": "SrEngineer",
                "Department": "Engineering",
                "Name": "SocratesDoe"
            }, {
                "Org": "Company3",
                "Position": "Manager",
                "Department": "Engineering",
                "Name": "BaconDoe"
            }, {
                "Org": "Company3",
                "Position": "Intern",
                "Department": "Fetching",
                "Name": "NietzcheDoe"
            }]
        }
    ]
}$$ doc
)

select x.value:company_data[0]:Org::string company_name
    , find_manager(x.value:company_data)
from data, table(flatten(parse_json(doc):company)) x;
```

[image]